# How to retrieve public constants in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, module, constants

I am working on an large Excel VBA project that needs to output an monthly report. As such I have a number of variables that I need to change monthly and that appear a lot throughout my code. I know i can declare Public constants, however I am just not able to retrieve these in different modules.

So how do I solve this as flexibly and easily as possible/how can I retrieve public constants in different modules?

E.G how can i retrieve:

```
Public Const startWeekProjection As Integer = 1609
```

in another module?

Comment: Just use it anywhere in a Module code sheet or a worksheet/thisworkbook code sheet. e.g. `debug.print startWeekProjection `. Just remember that `const` stands for *constant* so don't expect to change the assigned value. If you cannot use it anywhere in your project, more explanation is necessary to understand the situation.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, thanks for your respons and initial solution! I intent to use the following ' variables' widely:
* links (completely fixed)
* file names (change monthly)
* plan dates (setting changed per run of the system)
* plan horizon (setting changed per run)

So basically i have three types of variables or constants: completely fixed, fixed for a month and fixed per run only.

Comment: I will restate my question: what **exactly** is the problem? If you have put `Public Const startWeekProjection As Integer = 1609` into the **Declarations area** of a module code sheet but cannot use **startWeekProjection** ANYWHERE in your project then you have some serious problems.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, as I am still an beginner with Excel VBA I could also just not be aware of how I have to do this, so I really appriciate your help:)

What i would like to do is **declare all my constants in one module** and then **call/retrieve them in a number of other modules**

Comment: You are still not answering his question. You have stated clearly and several times what you *want* to do, but you aren't saying what's going wrong when you *try* to do it (or what you have tried).

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for me not answering you clear. I got the message 'ambiguous name detected'. After you made a super clear answer below I used a new name and it worked. So I guess I have to remove old variable declarations I have now right? 

And lots of thanks for helping me out guys!

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted out Vincent. Yes, once you use a var name as a public var available to all code sheets, it cannot be redeclared and used within subs. The sub wouldn't know which one you were talking about. (thanks for sticking with it until a resolution was found!)

Comment: Then I should be on track again, thanks!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your **const** vars into the **Declarations** area of a module code sheet.

[image: declarations area]

You can run MySub, MySecondSub or MyThirdSub and use the startWeekProjection const var.